# How to determine if render() was invoked by an explicit setState() call or by parent component passing props to it?

Tags: reactjs

I have two sibling components `RegionsDropdownComponent` and `CitiesDropdownComponent` inside a container `UpdateProfileFormComponent`.

At the on start, `UpdateProfileFormComponent` possess profile data ( that been pre fetched from server); region of profile is passed down as props to `RegionDropdownComponent`, while both region and city are passed down to `CitiesDropdownComponent`.

Within `CitiesDropdownComponent`, region is used to filter a cities dropdown so that dropdown reflects only cities belonging to region, while city is used to set city input field.
In the `render()` method of `CitiesDropdownComponent`, its `props.region` and `props.city` are used.

What's more, when user selects a different option from `RegionsDropdownComponent`, then a `handleChange()` in parent `UpdateProfileFormComponent` would call `this.setState()` so that `UpdateProfileFormComponent` would pass selected region and empty string props to `CitiesDropdownComponent`, which then re-filters its cities dropdown and also set city input to empty.

So far so good.

Now there is also a 3rd sibling `AgenciesDropdownComponent` that is independent from but similar to `CitiesDropdownComponent` in that it depends on `RegionsDropdownComponent` to filter a agencies dropdown and to set/reset a agency input field.
Returning to `CitiesDropdownComponent`, when a user selects a different option from cities dropdown, I would like a `handleChange()` method in `CitiesDropdownComponent` that would call `this.setState({city:selected_option_value})` ... but then `render()` of `CitiesDropdownComponent` already uses `props` instead of `this.state`.

How do I attempt to reconcile these two conflicting requirements?

Comment: `render()` shouldn't have to know about that.

Comment: If componentWillRecieveProps() is called, the rendering is happening due to parent passing props.
setState does not call this lifecycle method

Answer (score 2):

When a component renders because of props update, `componentWillReceiveProps()` is called first. You can try to use this to discriminate what causes the rendering.

So in your case, you can try the following:

- `CitiesDropdownComponent` should always use state in `render()`, and you can simply update state from props in `componentWillReceiveProps`(at least for the `city`)

Comment: Hey, mguijarr, tks! i was able to resolve my problem using your feedback ... that saved my day!

Comment: Hey, mguijarr, tks! i was able to solve my problem using your feedback ... that saved my day!
I followed ur advice by pasting "this.state.city = this.props.city" inside  componentWillReceiveProps(){ } of CitiesDropdownComponent, and using "this.state.city" in CitiesDropdownComponent's render() method.
I would like to close the issue and award points to you ... but i can't seem to find a [ Like ] or [ Up ] button or something like that so that i can award points to you....